# How to disable sleep mode of Apple watch programmatically

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I am developing one application for apple watch. What problem I am facing is watch goes in sleeping mode after some time. I want to disable the sleep mode programmatically.

Any solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't in iWatch framework has not any API for Enable pr Disable idle Time for apple Watch

Comment: @NitinGohel do you have any source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of my knowledge and recent search on this topic, There is currently no `api` available to enable/disable sleep mode for Apple Watch programmatically.